# Google translate API Method to translate json format only value multidimentional

Tags: php, api, translate

I want to translate my json data but only the **value** using google translate api sdk **php**

here is example (basic), but the real is deeply multidimensional array (json)

```
{"name":"耐穿钢丝袜", "data":{"text":"夏季清凉透气优质精品钢丝袜女士出行必备袜子批发等产品"}}
```